# YouTube video stops/skips at advertisement

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

I'm recently experiencing that all of my YouTube videos stops downloading (and playing) whenever the Ad should come (it stops every time I get to the "yellow" sign). If it's in a playlist, right after the Ad (without showing it) skips to the next video. However it doesn't make any any inconvenience if the Ad is before the video, just if it's in the middle of it (in the first 10-15 sec usually). Also if there's no Ad at all it plays the video with no problem.

I have chrome installed and have the latest Flash player installed just now, and disabled the one built-in Flash player in Chrome that can be found in the PepperFlash directory. So I assume that it's not a problem caused by that. I've also tried to reproduce the this phenomena with Internet Explorer, but it works perfetcly well.

Any idea what should stop this behaviour of YouTube in Chrome?